# Changing multiple columns with set in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to change lines and columns in data.table using `set` for efficiency.

The documentation on `set` states that the argument j is:
"Column name(s) (character) or number(s) (integer) to be assigned value when column(s) already exist, and only column name(s) if they are to be created."

and value argument is:
"A list of replacement values to assign by reference to x[i, j]."

However, I'm getting an error. This is an example code:

```
iris = as.data.table(iris)
set(iris,i=1L,j=as.integer(1:3),value=list(1:3))
```

this is the error I'm getting:

*Error in set(iris, i = 1L, j = as.integer(1:3), value = list(1:3)) : 
  Supplied 3 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'Sepal.Length'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.*

I know I can use the other alternatives to assign it, but `set` is MUCH more efficient. I'd like to know if this is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using `set` for multiple columns, then loop it

```
library(data.table)
for(j in 1:3) set(iris, i = 1L, j = j, value = j)
head(iris, 2)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1:          1.0         2.0          3.0         0.2  setosa
#2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done more easily

```
data(iris)
iris[1, 1:3] <- as.list(1:3)
head(iris, 2)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          1.0           2          3.0         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9           3          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: If I need to loop, there goes my efficiency!

Comment: @RicardoFernandesCampos no, it is not the case.  Here, we are doing the loop by columns

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks!